# Specify port for url_for

Tags: python, flask

How can I specify the port used for the Flask `url_for` method? Or, can I configure Flask to use whatever port it is running on for `url_for`? My issue is that I'm running a server on port 8080 but `url_for` does not add this port to any URLs generated, so any generated URLs use port 80 and do not resolve.

Comment: It should already include the port if necessary. How are you running the app (wsgi/dev server)?

Comment: For debugging I'm using the built-in Flask server on port 5000. url_for does not add this port to any of its URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to specify a port in `url_for` is to use the `_external=True` argument like so:

```
url_for('handle_contact_form', _external=True)
```

This generates a URL like `http://localhost:5000/contact-us`. Unfortunately a `:5000/contact-us` isn't a valid relative URL. So without using a full, external URL, the port cannot be specified.